# Ajax vs IE9-IE10

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Доброго дня.
Пытаюсь реализовать google maps с возможностью у пользователя вводить свой адрес в input type="text"
Во всех браузерах чудесным образом всё работает. IE9-11 напрочь отказывается реагировать на введение адреса.
Сдается мне, что дело в кроссдоменности аяксового запроса.

Код:

```
function calcRouteAdress() {
            var input=$('.address_input');
            var address=input.val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+encodeURIComponent(address),
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                if(response.results.length) {
                responseCoords=new google.maps.LatLng(response.results[0].geometry.location.lat, response.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
                calcRoute(responseCoords);
                }
            }
        });
        }
        $('.adress_input').bind('keypress',function(e){
            if(e.which==13) {
                calcRouteAdress();
            };
        })
    })
```

Может кто сталкивался с данной проблемой совместимости пользовательской формы в google maps и глюками в IE9-11?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362474/jquery-ajax-fails-in-ie-on-cross-domain-calls
Здесь смотрели?

Comment: Посмотрел - не помогло.